# Oculus Developer Hub hangs on "Installing..." for everything under the Downloads category

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

Prior to today, everything was working fine and I was able to deploy from Unity to specifically an APK. I wasn't able to operate in "Play" mode so I tried updating the Oculus Platform SDK, which proceeded to hang in "Installing..." forever, leading to my current predicament.

What happens:

1. I hit "download" on anything inside the Downloads section of the Oculus Developer Hub
2. It hangs saying "Installing..." for hours and does nothing.

Also, when I try to change my ADB Path in Oculus Developer Hub, it "fails" and asks me to try again, but the new value is present every time.

I've tried installing/uninstalling both ODH and Oculus software. I've tried changing the ADB path. I've tried installing and adding JRE and NDK to the path. I'm running out of options here. Does anyone have any advice? This is blocking me from doing development work in Unity.

Comment: I have the same problem. It used to work and I even tried updating installed apps, and instead it just kept "updating..." and when I finally restarted the app, it would no longer have that installed app installed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid issues, ODH (Oculus Developer Hub) must reference the same *adb.exe* as the one referenced by your Unity Editor.

If, for instance, you are using the Unity Editor 2021.3.1f1 with the standard settings (you didn't changed the default installation path and also installed the *Android Build Support* module and the corresponding sub-modules), then Unity will use the *adb.exe* found in:

```
 C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

ODH has a buggy behavior when trying to change the ADB path (*ODH > Settings > General > ADB Path > Edit*): when you select the desired adb path from the *Detected ADB Clients* drop down and click *Restart ODH*, you get the following error message:

> "Unable to change ADB path and restart ODH. Please try again."

[image]

Just ignore the error message. Dont' click *Cancel*, just close ODH and start it again. Then navigate again to the menu where you changed the ADB path, i.e. *ODH > Settings > General > ADB Path > Edit*. You should now have the path you chose before manually restarting ODH.